# Wrong constructor is called when two classes of the same name are in different files

Tags: lua

I'm fairly new to Lua. My co-worker asked me to work with his code while he's on a leave. I'm having a problem I couldn't find an answer for (or couldn't get my query right).

I have two Lua scripts with classes imitating types in our C program.
File A and B both contain identical class typeA:

```
type1 = {
  new = function(self,num)
    local o = {
      _data_num = {},
      _data = {},
      _size = {},
    }
    o._data_num = num
    for i=1, num do
      o._data[i] = type2:new()
    end
    o._size = o._data[1]:getSize()
    setmetatable(o,self)
    return o
  end,
<some other functions>
```

Also both files contain class type2 bearing the same name but with different code. Both of them are marked as required in file C.
My script crashed when instantiating type1 in file C because constructor for wrong type2 is called in the process (from B instead of A).

Can someone please offer me some workaround?
Putting files in different folders doesn't work.

Comment: Don't use two global classes/etc. with the same name since that can't work? If they are namespaced by module it should work fine but if they are both global then it can't work (only one global with a given name can exist).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess there's no other choice but renaming all these classes